# How to stop a Python script running in the background on Windows 10?

Tags: python, pyautogui

i'm currently doing pyautogui with python, so i created a script in notepad like this-

```
import pyautogui

numberdecider = "aa"

for char in numberdecider:
  pyautogui.write("Hello World!", interval=2.0)
```

So I went in command prompt and I wrote

```
pythonw script.py
```

Which ran my script in the background. What command should I use to stop this script using cmd because now whenever I try to type something it keeps typing "Hello World!" in between.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+C?

Comment: I did it just know and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `sys.exit` for keyboard interrupt like this:

```
import sys
import pyautogui

try:
   numberdecider = "aa"

   for char in numberdecider:
      pyautogui.write("Hello World!", interval=2.0)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

When you press `ctrl+c` in cmd it should stop the script.

Comment: I don't know about the code, but ctrl + c worked for me. Thanks!